# Angular 2 form returns empty value

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-forms

I have this simple form in Angular 2. I want to get the email and pass but I get an empty object.

login.component.html

```
<div class="container">
  <form #formData='ngForm' (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(formData)">
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="inputEmail" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Email</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email" (ngModel)="email" required>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="inputPassword" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Password</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password" (ngModel)="password" required>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <div class="offset-sm-2 col-sm-10">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="!formData.valid">Sign in</button>
        <a routerLink="/signup">Don't have an account?</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

auth.component.ts

```
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app/auth/login.component.html'
})
onSubmit(formData) {
      console.log(formData.value);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.email` and `this.password` `ngModel`s already contain the info you need.

```
onSubmit(formData) {
      console.log(this.email, this.password);
}
```

Comment: Solved my issue.I was missing `name="email"` and `name="password"`  from the inputs. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @RaduLucut glad you figured it out :)